# Clear data (list/dict/tuple) outside of function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm writing a program, and after I loop through some specific data stored in a variable, I no longer need it.  However, I would like to reuse the variable for use later in the program.  I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it seems like getting rid of data that's no longer needed and reusing the variable would keep code cleaner and use less resources.

Example:

```
  data = [#Lots and lots of data]

  def loopThroughdata(data):
     #here I loop through data and extract what I need
     #Finally, I'd like to reset the data variable to empty
     data = []
```

I've tried this resetting the data variable as in the example above, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Am I missing the point of why this isn't possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a scoping issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your function should be `global data` to signify that the data variable that you are using in the function is the one you have declared globally.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this does not work is that you have two distinct *variables* here.  Inside the function, when you say

```
data = []
```

you are changing the *parameter* `data` to a new empty list, but you are not changing the global variable `data` at all.

Strangely enough even though there are two variables here, the value of each variable is actually a reference to storage containing the list elements.  You can actually empty this storage by saying

```
data[:] = []
```

That will have the effect of making the global `data` empty.

Example:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3]
>>> def something(data):
...     print data
...     data[:] = []
... 
>>> print data
[1, 2, 3]
>>> something(data)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> data
[]
```

This has to do with the idea that in Python, everything is passed by value, but the "value" of an object is a reference to the object.

As to whether you *should* "empty out" lists and "reuse" variables for other uses later, that does sound a little strange, but I guess it depends on what you are trying to do.